# Which diode configuration do I need for this solid state relay?

Tags: diodes, relay, solid-state-relay

I want to add snubber or supression protection diodes for a solid state relay. Here is the diagram without the diodes:

[image]

And this is the SSR I'm going to use:
http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/solid-state-relays/0346895/

What kind of diodes I need and where to place them? The load is a speed controller together with a single phase inductive fan-motor and will not draw more than 1A in steady state.

Comment: The datasheet shows a built-in snubber as an option; why do you think you need more? If you get one without a snubber, the equivalent schematic shows clearly where it is placed (values may be interesting to find, though).

Comment: Sorry I don't understand if I order this relay, how can I know if it has built in snubber?

Comment: Btw someone shows connections for the AC output of the same realy totally different here: http://www.hobbyprojects.com/quick_circuits_reference/microcontroller_circuits/images/mrc3.GIF Isnt that wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RS state that that unit has an internal snubber but don't give the full Crydom part number so you can check.

[image]

*Figure 1. Extract from [Crydom Series 1 datasheet](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/1265/0900766b812651ef.pdf).*

Contact RS and ask them for the full part number.

Comment: Thanks the snubber they show is R C in series not a diode. Why is that?

Comment: Wikipedia has a good paragraph on [RC snubbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snubber#RC_snubbers). It should give you a good appreciation.

Comment: Using diode snubbers with AC power gets... complicated, RC snubbers don't have that problem